# How do I get detailed error messages from httpd in a systemd distro?

Tags: fedora, apache

Fedora changed to systemd so now when I try to start httpd I get the error message

```
[]$ systemctl restart httpd.service
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
```

When I look in /var/log/httpd/error_log I do not see any startup error messages.
When I look in /var/log/messages I do not see any startup error messages. Where are they? Do I need to enable an option?

Forgot to add the following command response

```
[]$ systemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - LSB: start and stop Apache HTTP Server
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd)
      Active: failed since Tue, 24 Jan 2012 23:32:37 +0000; 8min ago
     Process: 1061 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that was written to standard output or standard error should have been sent to `/var/log/messages` by default - that is standard `systemd` behaviour from F16 on.

With `httpd` most errors are also likely to have been sent to `/var/log/httpd/error_log` at the same time that they were sent to the console.

If you're still on F15 then things are trickier, and you will probably have to dodge `systemd` to see anything that was sent to the console as it doesn't capture the output to the log. Set `SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT` in your environment and start `httpd` with `/etc/init.d/httpd start` to see them.